# Indicate to a C application a MySQL column value change

Tags: mysql, c

I have a C application that should do some processing based on a particular value of a certain column in a MySQL table. The said column though is being updated by another application. Is polling for this column value my only option ?

Comment: What do you want when you say "Is polling for this column value my only option ?" Be more specific with your question, otherwise no one is able to help you. Be Wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not your only option, but it's probably the best option.

You could have an update trigger that calls a user defined function, and have that function execute your program.  Doing something like that in a trigger is generally not a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

What I interpret about your problem is that you have two applications say A1 and A2, A1 does some modification in the MySQL table T and based on whether some updation has happened on T or not, A2 does some processing.

I think polling should be a good option.You can also use the "information_schema" database to find when T was last updated.This can be achieved in the following manner :

SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'T'

Alternatively if you dont want to poll, you can make A1 talk to A2, in case it has to do the required changes in T.

But its a tradeoff b/w both the approaches which only you could analyze.